# Does the Xbox One controller have a cable for PC and the new 3.5mm headphone jack?

Tags: controllers

I'm going to buy an Xbox One controller to play PC games. What I'm not sure of though is, does the Xbox One controller come with cable for PC or (Window 10) and have the new 3.5mm headphone jack?

Comment: Have you uad a look at the steam controller? http://store.steampowered.com/app/353370/.  I know that's not what you are asking but just thought I would put it out there

Answer (score 2):

Nope , **Wired** Xbox controller does not come  with 3.5 mm headset jack , only **wireless** controller for Xbox One have 3.5 mm headphone jack which is included from 2015 so you will need a wireless controller to use headset on PC.

Comment: All you have to do is buy a wireless one, then get a micro USB cable to plug it into your PC.  You could get it working wireless as well, but I'm not to familiar with how to set that up. Edit: It seems like the new Xbox One S controllers has Bluetooth built in, so that might make it easier to connect wirelessly.

Comment: 1 more question, if i buy the new wireless xbox 1 controller it comes with 3.5mm jack right? Then do i need to buy the wireless adapter?  And sometimes if i want to use wired if im close to my pc can i plug and play with the wireless one too?

Comment: @HyunJaeJung I thought my last comment explained the wired part.  Yes you can plug in your wireless controller into your PC and it will work.  And all Xbox One Controllers from 2015 on have a 3.5 millimeter jack for headphone use.  [See this Image](http://compass.xboxlive.com/assets/11/26/1126f021-3363-40e7-9863-cbf4421484e6.png?n=one-controller-headphone-push-l.png).  I will also note, that if you get a controller that does not have the 3.5mm jack, you can get an adapter piece so that you can still use a 3.5mm jack headphone.

Comment: Do i need to buy the adapter for the wireless controller?